# Prepared statements login need to get raw

Tags: php

I am learning to make prepared statements and I am doing the login again, but I have a problem, it is the following:

When I make the query ("SELECT clave from users where user =? && email =?"); How can I get the data of the key column safely? I need the key column to verify the hash password

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials covering `password_verify` and prepared statements, you should read some and the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `mysqli_stmt_bind_result()` to get the column value into a variable.

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($resultado, $clave);
$print = mysqli_stmt_fetch($resultado);
if ($print) {
    if (password_verify($password, $clave)) {
        ...
    }
}
```